# How to find a range of given number?

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table like below and I want to find the range of inputted number.
ex) if users enters 84, MySql query returns B.

```
Rank  Range_Start Range_End
A       90          100
B       80          89
C       70          79
.
.
H
I        0          10
```

Comment: `WHERE 84 BETWEEN Range_Start AND Range_End` -- something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

```
SELECT Rank FROM tbl WHERE Range_Start < my_value AND Range_End > my_value
```

Or (if you *don't* need *strict* inclusion):

```
SELECT Rank FROM tbl WHERE my_value BETWEEN Range_Start AND Range_End
```

Comment: thanks for answer. its solved my problem too in sql server where i was trying it and searching for last 2hrs.